# Delete SharePoint Modern Page comments using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

I have a Site Pages library in Communication Site. I have to delete comments posted by 2 users on all the pages using PowerShell.

There are many solutions available which use REST but I prefer to use PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used PnP PowerShell here,

```
$SiteURL="https://yoyo.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite"
$UserName="user@username.com"
$Password = "password"
$ListName = "Site Pages"
$deleteEmails = "baduser1@gmail.com","baduser2@yahoo.com"
 
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

#Get all list items from list in batches
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "ID" -PageSize 500

Write-host "Total Items:" $($ListItems.Count)
 
ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{ 
    Try
    {
        $Comments = Get-PnPListItemComment -List $ListName -Identity $Item["ID"]

        foreach($Comment in $Comments)
        {
            if($deleteEmails -contains $Comment.Author.LoginName.Replace("i:0#.f|membership|",""))
            {
                Write-Host "Id :" $Item["ID"]
                
                try
                {
                    Remove-PnPListItemComment -List $ListName -Identity $Item["ID"] -Text $Comment.Text -Force
                }
                Catch 
                {
                    Write-Host -f Red "Error while removing commnet:" $_.Exception.Message
                    Log-Message "Error while removing commnet:" $_.Exception.Message
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Catch 
    {
        Write-Host -f Red "Error while getting comments:" $_.Exception.Message
        Log-Message "Error while getting comments:" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of `PnP.PowerShell` are you using? I am getting `The term 'Get-PnPListItemComment' is not recognized ...` with version `1.10.0`.